# How to check if string s is inside of the List<string> in Dictionary<int, List<string>> in c#?

Tags: c#

I have a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`  `enrolledStudents`

The `key` is an int, which is a paper code.
The `value` is a list of strings, where the strings are students names

What I am wanting to know is how do I check to see if a `string s` is inside this List inside of `enrolledStudents`

For example

```
if(string s in List<string> of enrolledStudents){
    return enrolledStudent.key;
}
```

Comment: If you want to query the dictionary by student name and get the paper code, try using Dictionary<string, int> where key is the student name and paper code is the value. Then you can simply use if (enrolledStudents.ContainsKey(studentName)) return enrolledStudents[studentName];

Comment: but what if I have multiple paper per student? because they will enroll in more than one paper.

Comment: Good point, so you mention an n-to-n relation. Looks like you need to make a design decision. If most of your queries will be "who enrolled in a specific paper", keep it your way and use @M.kazem Akhgary's answer below, and if most of your queries will be "which papers a specific student enrolled in", then use mine after changing the value type to List<int>. If you will make both types of queries as often, you can use both at the same time by declaring two dictionaries, but be careful with data consistency.

Comment: I need to do both, I need to be able to select a paper(key) and see which students are enrolled. And I also need to be able to select a student(value) and see how many keys this student belongs to

Comment: Can I not have one dictionary and select whether i want to return all of the students in a particular paper, or all of the papers that a student belongs to?

Comment: Technically you can do it by using Dictionary<object, List<object>> and deal with all the casting and null checks. But it is not a good idea, actually it is a bad bad idea. "Just because you can, does not mean you should" :)

Comment: You can do it with your current dictionary. You already have all the students for a particular paper code, which is `enrolledStudents[paperCode]`. To get all the paperCodes that a student belongs to, you would have to loop through all the items in the dictionary, and return the keys for the items whose value contains the student name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions without LINQ

//1-st solution

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> group = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
List<string> newList = new List<string> { "Orange", "Strawberry", "Banana"};
group.Add(1, newList); //Group of Fruits

newList = new List<string> { "Hulk", "Spiderman", "Batman" };
group.Add(2, newList); //Group of Super-Heroes

int GroupKey = 0;
foreach(var groupItem in group)
{
    foreach(var stringValue in groupItem.Value)
    {
        if(stringValue == "Spiderman")
        {
            GroupKey = groupItem.Key;
            break;
        }
    } 
    if(GroupKey > 0)
        break
}
```

//2-nd solution which I think you should use in your case 
(because for every student there is only one key(number) maybe it is better to use string and not List, only if you are working with the groups of the students you should consider 1-st solution)

```
Dictionary<int, string> enrolledStudents = new Dictionary<int, string>(); 
enrolledStudents.Add(1, "Jamie Fox");  //Student 1 
enrolledStudents.Add(2, "Arnold Spenser");  //Student 2
enrolledStudents.Add(3, "Jack & Jones");  //Student 3

int StudentNumber = 0;
foreach (var student in enrolledStudents)
{
    if(student.Value == "Arnold Spenser")
    {
        StudentNumber = student.Key;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all the paper codes for a specific student, you can just do:

```
List<int> paperCodesForStudent = enrolledStudents
    .Where(item => item.Value.Contains("studentName"))
    .Select(item => item.Key)
    .ToList();
```

You could make this a method, and you could also add a case-insensitive comparison for the name check:

```
private static List<int> GetPaperCodesForStudent(string studentName,
    Dictionary<int, List<string>> enrolledStudents)
{
    return enrolledStudents
        .Where(item => item.Value.Any(name =>
            name.Equals(studentName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        .Select(item => item.Key)
        .ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using linq

```
return enrolledStudents.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(s)).Key;
```

note that this search is linear.
as mentioned in comments you  could recreate another dictionary once to optimize search speed.

```
Dictionary<string, List<int>> pageMap = enrolledStudents
                    .SelectMany(kvp =>
                        kvp.Value.Select(value => new { Key = value, Value = kvp.Key }))
                    .GroupBy(a => a.Key)
                    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Select(x => x.Value).ToList());
```

now you can use pagemap to get pages from students like this.

```
return pageMap[s];
```

Comment: I may be misreading it but if you are flattening the list but trying to use the same key won't you get issues with duplicate keys?

Comment: First part does not seem to be linear. If there are n classes and m students, in worst case such as querying for a nonexistent student name the complexity will be O(nm).

Comment: It is linear still. Its not exponential. @burkay

Answer (score 0):

```
Dictionary<int, List<string>> enrolledStudents = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();
bool any = enrolledStudents.Any(x => x.Value.Contains("myString"));
```

Or if you want the first key

```
var key = enrolledStudents.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Value.Contains(s))?.Key ?? "";
```

Note the single question mark if FirstOrDefault() returns a null.